# If statement only works one way when comparing doubles?

Tags: c, if-statement, double

This code is meant to find the most expensive beer from a list of beers in "pivo.txt".
When it's looking for the cheapest beer, the if statement is executed and the program works fine but when i turn the comparison sign from > to < it never executes.
Is this a logical problem or does it have something to do with comparing floats (casting them to int didn't work)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct{
    char ime[50];
    double kol;
    double cijena;
}pivo;

char* cheap_price(pivo *p,int n)
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    double raz,maxraz;
    maxraz = p[i].kol/p[i].cijena;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
        raz = p[i].cijena/p[i].kol;
        printf("%lf\n",raz);
        if(raz<maxraz)
        {
            maxraz = raz;
            printf("min%lf\n",maxraz);
            j=i;
        }
    }
    return p[j].ime;
}

int main()
{
    pivo *p;
    int n,i;
    FILE *file = fopen("pivo.txt","r");
    fscanf(file,"%d",&n);
    p = (pivo*)malloc(n*sizeof(pivo));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        fscanf(file,"%s %lf %lf",p[i].ime,&p[i].kol,&p[i].cijena);
    printf("\nCheapest beer is %s",cheap_price(p,n));
}
```

The txt file looks like this

```
9
Zlatorog 0.33 13.00
Calsberg 0.5 17.00
Ozujsko 0.5 13.00
Stella 0.33 13.00
Tuborg 0.5 15.00
Karlovacko 0.33 14.00
Guiness 0.33 18.00
Bavaria 0.25 15.00
Becks 0.33 17.00
```

And the debug from the printf I've placed inside the if statement is empty (if never executes)

Comment: The put more printfs in it.

Comment: Is it `kol/cijena` (as in the initial assignment to `maxraz`) or `cijena/kol` (as in the loop)???

Comment: Compile and run the prograqm, no warnings, list of results and `Cheapest beer is Zlatorog`. Although from eyeballing the data, should be equal to `Stella`.

Comment: @pmg It's kol/cijena since it's looking for the worst liter/money variable.

Comment: Had the same. Also when I changed the comparison to `>` I got Bavaria. I didn't look at the algorithm, so @Mr. Poopybutthole, your assumption is wrong.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Since I don't know why it's happening the amount of code is obviously as minimal as it can be. I've provided everything you need to compile it yourself therefore it's complete and it reproduces the problem after each change that i've stated in the begining so it's verifiable. Where is the problem?

Comment: The proper way is to look for price/liters, to keep the logic simple. Should change maxraz = p[i].cijena/p[i].kol, so it matches raz.  The mismatch causes the max value to never get updated, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it `kol/cijena` (as in the initial assignment to `maxraz`) or `cijena/kol` (as in the loop)???

```
char* cheap_price(pivo *p,int n)
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    double raz,maxraz;
    maxraz = p[i].kol/p[i].cijena;
    //            ^^^      ^^^^^^
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
        raz = p[i].cijena/p[i].kol;
        //         ^^^^^^      ^^^
        printf("%lf\n",raz);
```